# Proof by contradiction in Coq

Tags: coq, type-theory

I am trying to understand the apparent paradox of the logical framework of theorem provers like Coq not including LEM yet also being able to construct proofs by contradiction. Specifically the intuitionistic type theory that these theorem provers are based on does not allow for any logical construction of the form ￢(￢P)⇒P, and so what is required in order to artificially construct this in a language like Coq? And how is the constructive character of the system preserved if this is allowed?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing up two related uses of contradiction in logic. One is the technique of *proof by contradiction*, which says that you can prove `P` by proving `~ (~ P)` -- that is, by showing that `~ P` entails a contradiction. This technique is actually *not* available in general in constructive logics like Coq, unless one of the following applies.

1. You add the excluded middle `forall P, P \/ ~ P` as an axiom. Coq supports this, but this addition means that you are not working in a constructive logic anymore.
2. The proposition `P` is known to be decidable (i.e., `P \/ ~ P` holds).  This is the case, for example, for the equality of two natural numbers `n` and `m`, which we can prove by induction.
3. The proposition `P` is of the form `~ Q`. Since `Q -> ~ (~ Q)` holds constructively, by the law of contrapositives (which is also valid constructively), we obtain `~ (~ (~ Q)) -> (~ Q)`.

The other use of contradiction is the [*principle of explosion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), which says that anything follows once you assume a contradiction (i.e., `False` in Coq). Unlike proof by contradiction, the principle of explosion is *always* valid in constructive logic, so there is no paradox here.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand this correctly, even if one were to add the axiom `forall P, P \/ ~ P`, Coq itself is still operating within a constructive logic framework, but the internal language in which the proof is written is not. And so this layer of abstraction vs. what the compiler is actually doing can be described with the language-metalanguage distinction. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlanAudia, I am not sure I see what you mean by a "constructive logic framework". Coq is implemented in a way that is agnostic to whether you use the excluded middle in proofs or not, so you might say that it is constructive in that sense even if you decide to add the excluded middle later as an axiom. But I believe this terminology would be non-standard; usually when we talk about "constructive", we are solely referring to the language for writing proofs.

Answer (score 0):

In constructive logic, by definition, a contradiction is an inhabitant of the empty type **0**, and, also by definition, the negation ￢P of a proposition P is a function of type: P -> **0** that gives an inhabitant of the empty type **0** from an inhabitant (a proof) of P.

If you assume an inhabitant (proof) of P, and derive constructively an inhabitant of **0**, you have defined a function inhabiting the type P -> **0**, i.e. a proof of ￢P. This is a constructive sort of proof by contradiction: assume P, derive a contradiction, conclude ￢P.

Now if you assume ￢P and derive a contradiction, you have a constructive proof of ￢￢P, but cannot conclude constructively that you have a proof of P: for this you need the LEM axiom.